# How to check through Delphi if a record exist in MS Access(Database)?

Tags: delphi, login-system

Hi I have a Delphi 7 project task where we need to include a login system. I have a register page where the data goes to a table in Access. Now when the user needs to login it needs to check if his/her information exist and then  he would be granted permission to go further, but  don't know how to do this.

Comment: Try first, then ask. There must be at least *something* you have figured out along the way.

Comment: Surely you can search for how to use Delphi and ADO with Access, and at least come up with *some sort* of effort to do this yourself first. Google 'delphi database tutorial', at least.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I upgraded to 2005 and on, so I am unable to test it for Delphi 7, but in Delphi 2005 and on at least, you can use the following procedure:

```
USES {$IFDEF UseParmsEvenThoughTheyAreNotNecessary } DB {$ELSE } StrUtils {$ENDIF } ,ADODB;

FUNCTION CanLogIn(CONST UserName,Password : STRING ; CONST AccessDatabaseFile,TableName,UserField,PasswordField : STRING) : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    Connection : TADOConnection;
    DataSet    : TADODataSet;

  FUNCTION AccessConnStr(CONST FileName : STRING) : STRING;
    BEGIN
      {$IFDEF CPUX64 }
        Result:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source='+FileName
      {$ELSE }
        Result:='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.0;Data Source='+FileName
      {$ENDIF }
    END;

  {$IFNDEF UseParmsEvenThoughTheyAreNotNecessary }
    FUNCTION QuotedStr(CONST STR : STRING) : STRING;
      BEGIN
        Result:=''''+ReplaceStr(STR,'''','''''')+''''
      END;
  {$ENDIF }

  BEGIN
    Connection:=TADOConnection.Create(NIL);
    TRY
      Connection.ConnectionString:=AccessConnStr(AccessDatabaseFile);
      TRY
        Connection.Connected:=TRUE;
        TRY
          DataSet:=TADODataSet.Create(NIL);
          TRY
            DataSet.CommandType:=cmdText;
            {$IFDEF UseParmsEvenThoughTheyAreNotNecessary }
              DataSet.ParamCheck:=TRUE;
              DataSet.Parameters.CreateParameter('UserName',ftString,pdInput,80,UserName);
              DataSet.Parameters.CreateParameter('Password',ftString,pdInput,80,Password);
              DataSet.CommandText:='SELECT * FROM ['+TableName+'] WHERE ['+UserField+']=:UserName AND ['+PasswordField+']=:Password';
            {$ELSE }
              DataSet.ParamCheck:=FALSE;
              DataSet.CommandText:='SELECT * FROM ['+TableName+'] WHERE ['+UserField+']='+QuotedStr(UserName)+' AND ['+PasswordField+']='+QuotedStr(Password);
            {$ENDIF }
            TRY
              DataSet.Open;
              TRY
                Result:=NOT DataSet.EOF
              FINALLY
                DataSet.Close
              END
            EXCEPT
              Result:=FALSE
            END
          FINALLY
            DataSet.Free
          END
        FINALLY
          Connection.Close
        END
      EXCEPT
        Result:=FALSE
      END
    FINALLY
      Connection.Free
    END
  END;
```

Parameters:

```
UserName = Name of the user attempting to log in
Password = Password of the user
AccessDatabaseFile = The access database file
TableName = The name of the table containing the UserName/Password for allowed users
UserField = The name of the field in the above table that contains the user name
PasswordField = The name of the field in the above table that contains the password for the user
```

If an exception occurs (file not found, wrong table name/field names or what have you), the function catches these and returns FALSE. Only if the entire function is successful and the user is found in the table with the correct password, does the function return TRUE.

Comment: Even if this would be so, using parameters is always the right thing to do. As an added bonus you don't have to do the QuotedStr mess! (FYI QuotedStr is a function that exists in Delphi)

Comment: "Right" by whose definition? Certainly not mine. If not only "would be so" (safe from SQL injection) - is IS so. I have challenged people before, and never have they been able to do SQL injection with this type of SQL statement build. Can you? :-)

Comment: See http://www.sqlinjectionwiki.com/Categories.aspx?catId=6 and http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/511061/30/8400/threaded  for why your code is a fail.

Comment: Once again: Give me values for UserName and Password that allows SQL injection. No one I have challenged in the past have been able to do so, and until proven otherwise, I stand by my claim that it isn't possible...

Comment: A few comments: There is a build in `QuotedStr` function in Delphi. The code above is NOT subject to SQL injection since it does not uses `\'` for escaping single quotes. Using parameters in NON-Unicode Delphi (e.g. 7) will break a Unicode (`WideString`) parameters.

Comment: @HeartWare again, I am not saying your code is injection vulnerable  but where do you draw the line between "oh I am sure this query is not injectable" and "Now I have to use parameters because of security concerns"? If you always use parameters, you don't have to pose yourself that question, period. IMHO It's a bad coding practice (Ask Sony and many other hacked companies ;) )

Comment: @kobik: Delphi7 is really getting old now :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy, Tell me about it. but some of us can't afford the time/$ to switch a huge application to a modern Delphi version :/ Anyway, if Unicode is not an issue I would definitely use parameters in this case which is always a good practice. but down-voting an answer *automatically* because parameters are not used is wrong IMHO. specially since you can't prove the above answer is subject to SQL injection. HeartWare could edit his answer and propose an alternative.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: I understand your argument, but that was not what was said. It was explicitly said that my code was vulnerable to SQL code injection, and I categorically deny this and will continue to do so until someone proves otherwise. If the statement had been "it's better in general to use parameters", then I wouldn't have complained (I might even have agreed), but categorically stating (wrongly) that my code is SQL code injection vulnerable will not be tolerated, when it clearly isn't.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: With respect to you "not saying my code is injection vulnerable", how else would you interpret your "Even IF this WOULD be so" (my emphasis). With that statement you are indirectly saying that the code IS vulnerable - at least that's how I read it - and that statement will always be challenged...

Comment: So - now one can define the conditional {$DEFINE UseParmsEvenThoughTheyAreNotNecessary } if they insist on slowing down the program with more lines of code, even if they aren't necessary.

Comment: That's better. You see, no more QuotedStr mess! ;)

Comment: I think the other code is more of a mess than the QuotedStr function call. Why use 3 lines to do something that can be (just as easily and just as safely) done in one?